# K-means with initial centers

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm doing K-means clustering of n points and k centers.

To start off, here's my code so far:

A class for a point:

```
public class Point
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }


    public Point()
    {
        Id = -1;
        X = -1;
        Y = -1;
    }

    public Point(int id, double x, double y)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    public static double FindDistance(Point pt1, Point pt2)
    {
        double x1 = pt1.X, y1 = pt1.Y;
        double x2 = pt2.X, y2 = pt2.Y;

        double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x2 - x1, 2.0) + Math.Pow(y2 - y1, 2.0));
        return (distance);
    }
}
```

A class for data:

```
public class PointCollection : List<Point>
{

    public Point Centroid { get; set; }

    public PointCollection()
        : base()
    {
        Centroid = new Point();
    }

    public void AddPoint(Point p)
    {
        this.Add(p);
        UpdateCentroid();
    }

    public Point RemovePoint(Point p)
    {
        Point removedPoint = new Point(p.Id, p.X, p.Y);
        this.Remove(p);
        UpdateCentroid();

        return (removedPoint);
    }

    public void UpdateCentroid()
    {
        double xSum = (from p in this select p.X).Sum();
        double ySum = (from p in this select p.Y).Sum();
        Centroid.X = (xSum / (double)this.Count);
        Centroid.Y = (ySum / (double)this.Count);
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class KMeans
{
    public static List<PointCollection> DoKMeans(PointCollection points, int clusterCount)
    {
        List<PointCollection> allClusters = new List<PointCollection>();
        List<List<Point>> allGroups = ListUtility.SplitList<Point>(points, clusterCount);
        foreach (List<Point> group in allGroups)
        {
            PointCollection cluster = new PointCollection();
            cluster.AddRange(group);
            allClusters.Add(cluster);
        }

        int movements = 1;
        while (movements > 0)
        {
            movements = 0;

            foreach (PointCollection cluster in allClusters) 
            {
                for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < cluster.Count; pointIndex++) 
                {
                    Point point = cluster[pointIndex];

                    int nearestCluster = FindNearestCluster(allClusters, point);
                    if (nearestCluster != allClusters.IndexOf(cluster)) 
                    {
                        if (cluster.Count > 1) 
                        {
                            Point removedPoint = cluster.RemovePoint(point);
                            allClusters[nearestCluster].AddPoint(removedPoint);
                            movements += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return (allClusters);
    }

    public static int FindNearestCluster(List<PointCollection> allClusters, Point point)
    {
        double minimumDistance = 0.0;
        int nearestClusterIndex = -1;

        for (int k = 0; k < allClusters.Count; k++) 
        {
            double distance = Point.FindDistance(point, allClusters[k].Centroid);
            if (k == 0)
            {
                minimumDistance = distance;
                nearestClusterIndex = 0;
            }
            else if (minimumDistance > distance)
            {
                minimumDistance = distance;
                nearestClusterIndex = k;
            }
        }

        return (nearestClusterIndex);
    }
}
```

And finally helping function for list split:

```
public static List<List<T>> SplitList<T>(List<T> items, int groupCount)
    {
        List<List<T>> allGroups = new List<List<T>>();

        int startIndex = 0;
        int groupLength = (int)Math.Round((double)items.Count / (double)groupCount, 0);
        while (startIndex < items.Count)
        {
            List<T> group = new List<T>();
            group.AddRange(items.GetRange(startIndex, groupLength));
            startIndex += groupLength;

            if (startIndex + groupLength > items.Count)
            {
                groupLength = items.Count - startIndex;
            }

            allGroups.Add(group);
        }

        if (allGroups.Count > groupCount && allGroups.Count > 2)
        {
            allGroups[allGroups.Count - 2].AddRange(allGroups.Last());
            allGroups.RemoveAt(allGroups.Count - 1);
        }

        return (allGroups);
    }
```

So, now I'm trying to write a second method for the main class, which would accept a predefined starting centres. I have trouble grasping that though, as I can't find anything on the internet where the k-means algorithm would use initial centers. Can someone point me in a direction of such guide or give me any ideas how to modify the code? Thanks.

Edit: Maybe something more why am I trying to do this: I try to write LBG algorithm using k-means, like so https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat557/node/67

I can access the computed centers for splitting in each of the steps with my code, however I need to find a way to feed them back to the k-means class. Like, if I calculated the starting centre, i need to put this centre and another offset by epsilon into k-means algorithm.

Edit2: Code now in English(I hope)

Comment: Code is not readable as it not in English.

Comment: @weston Ok, I'll try to remake it in English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, maybe someone will use:

```
public static List<PointCollection> DoKMeans(PointCollection points, int clusterCount, Point[] startingCentres)
{
    // code...
    int ctr = 0;
    foreach (List<Point> group in allGroups)
    {
        PointCollection cluster = new PointCollection();
        cluster.c.X = startingCentres[ctr].X;
        cluster.c.Y = startingCentres[ctr].Y;
        cluster.AddRange(group);
        allClusters.Add(cluster);
    }
    // rest of code the same
}
```